# Why is OnRedirectToIdentityProvider not called in Net 6?

Tags: c#, events, identityserver4, .net-6.0

My project was written in Net Core 2.2.

Identity Server StartUp code:

```
app.UseForwardedHeaders().UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseResponseCompression();
if (env.IsDevelopment())
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
else { app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error"); app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Home/Error/{0}"); app.ConfigureHttpToHttpsRewrites(env); }
app.UseRouting();
app.UseIdentityServer();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "default", pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Configuration method:

```
public static void ConfigureAuthentication(this IServiceCollection services, IConfigurationRoot configuration)
{
    services
      .AddAuthentication(options =>
      {
          options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
          options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
      })
      .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options => { options.ReturnUrlParameter = "somePar"; })
      .AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
      {
          options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
          options.Authority = "IdentityServer");
          options.ResponseType = OidcConstants.ResponseTypes.CodeIdToken;
          options.ClientId = "ClientId";
          options.ClientSecret = "ClientSecret";
          options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
          options.SignedOutRedirectUri = websiteSettings.GetValue<string>("Home");
          options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
          options.Scope.Add("some");
          options.SaveTokens = true;
          options.RemoteAuthenticationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
          options.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "role";
          options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
          {
              OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>
              {
                  // breakpoint doesn`t call
                  // code..
              }
          }
      }
}
```

My class where call endpoint. These methods are in the same class:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> T1Async(Guid idd)
{
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) return RedirectToAction(nameof(CompleteAsync));
    // code..
}

[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
[HttpGet("complete/{requestId}")]
public async Task<ActionResult> CompleteAsync(Guid requestId)
{
    // some code..
}
```

Identity Server Clients settings:

```
public static Client[] Get(Settings settings)
{
    return new[]
    {
        new Client
        {
            ClientId = "clientId",
            ClientName = "clientName",
            ClientSecrets = { new Secret(secret.Sha256()) },
            AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials,
            AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Reference,
            Enabled = true,
            RequireConsent = false,
            AllowOfflineAccess = true,
            UpdateAccessTokenClaimsOnRefresh = true,
            AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = true,
            BackChannelLogoutUri = $"{settings.Home}/signout-oidc",
            PostLogoutRedirectUris = $"{settings.Home}/signout-callback-oidc",
            RedirectUris = {$"{settings.Home}/signin-oidc"},
            RefreshTokenUsage = TokenUsage.ReUse,
            RefreshTokenExpiration = TokenExpiration.Absolute,
            IdentityTokenLifetime = 300,
            AuthorizationCodeLifetime = 300,
            AccessTokenLifetime = 3600,
            AbsoluteRefreshTokenLifetime = 3600,
            RequirePkce = false,
            AllowedScopes = {"openid","profile"}
        }
    };
}
```

This code was work on .Net Core 2.2. Now it doesn`t call method. There are no errors

Any help on this appreciated!

Comment: How have you configured authorization? please post your UseXXXX(); methods too. typically in an OpenIDConnect setup you also have AddCookies, why not?

Comment: @ToreNestenius, I added addition information

Comment: can you post all your app.UseXXX() methods?

Comment: @ToreNestenius, I added UseXXX() methods from IDS Startup

Answer (score 0):

One problem that I see is this:

```
  .AddAuthentication(options =>
  {
      options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
  })
```

You typically only use OpenIDConnect for the challenge part, and you use Cookies for the rest, like this:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
```

Also, I always recommend that you put IdentityServer in it own service, just to make it more clear who is doing what. Otherwise it is pretty complex to debug.

Comment: It doesn`t  work

Comment: You typically should also add     app.UseAuthorization();

Comment: Your AddAuthentication() method is not the same as in my answer. Cookie should be the default scheme and openidconnect only handles challenge

Comment: I changed UseAuthorization in my project and added app.UseAuthorization(). did not work

Comment: What you want to do in OnRedirectToIdentityProvider ?